# Finding functions that give nice solutions to a recurrence relation.

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, functional-equations, closed-form

In a recent problem I was working through, I came across the following recurrence relation:
$$
\text{K}_1(x,\ t;\ g) = 1,\quad x, t\in\Bbb{R}\quad g\in\text{C}^1 \\
\text{K}_{n+1}(x,\ t;\ g) = g'(t)\int_t^{g(x)}\text{K}_n(\sigma,\ g(t);\ g)\text{d}\sigma
$$
where the given function parameter $g$ has at least one real fixed point $a$.

I'm looking for relatively simple functions $g$ such that this recurrence relation has a "nice" closed form formula for arbitrary $n$. Currently, the only thing I've found that results in anything even remotely simple is $g(x) = x$, which makes
$$
\text{K}_{n+1}(x,\ t;\ g)=\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}
$$
Nothing else seems to result in anything simple; $x^k$, $e^x - 1$ , $\ln(1 + x)$, $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, etc. Even $x^2$ results in $\text{K}_n$ being a polynomial in $x$ and $t$ of degree $6\left(2^n-\frac 12\right)$, but the coefficients on even only the $x^{6\left(2^n-\frac 12\right)}$ term don't appear to have any nice closed form (according to OEIS).

The problem seems to be related to finding functions $g$ where $g^{(-1)}(g(x))$ is relatively easy to calculate (with $g^{(-1)}=\int g$).

Any ideas on other functions $g$ that would result in a "nice" form for $\text{K}_n$? I know the idea of "nice" isn't well defined, but in this context it essentially means "has a closed form, not in terms of integrals, for arbitrary $n$ which is computable in a finite number of calculations" (i.e. no unevaluable infinite series)

Comment: Besides the one off odd examples, the machinery you want here is differential-galois theory/ difference-galois theory, which can be used to compute symmetry groups of these operator equations and determine if they have closed forms in some choice of function field. Now i'm not sure how that works but if you are willing to let this become a long term problem to work on, that would be helpful to you